# Store saved information

Tags: angularjs

i have four radio buttons. each value of buttons is binded to the value of its corresponding textarea. (e.g. textarea1 has ng-model ="c_a_multiple", the value of the first radio button which is letter A should be the value of typed in the textarea)my problem is when the page loads, and then when i clicked the first radio button, the fourth radio button is selected rather than the first one.

```
      <li><input type="radio" name="ChoiceGroup" ng-model="radio" ng-value="c_a_multiple">&nbsp;A</li>

      <li><textarea ng-model="c_a_multiple" placeholder="type your choice A here"></textarea></li>

      <li><input type="radio" name="ChoiceGroup" ng-model="radio" ng-value="c_b_multiple">&nbsp;B</li>

      <li><textarea ng-model="c_b_multiple" placeholder="type your choice B here"></textarea></li>

      <li><input type="radio" name="ChoiceGroup" ng-model="radio" ng-value="c_c_multiple">&nbsp;C</li>

      <li><textarea ng-model="c_c_multiple" placeholder="type your choice C here"></textarea></li>

      <li><input type="radio" name="ChoiceGroup" ng-model="radio" ng-value="c_d_multiple">&nbsp;D</li>

      <li><textarea ng-model="c_d_multiple" placeholder="type your choice D here"></textarea></li>
```

[see this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UpbJKoJNMkQSgDLKl2vj?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you initially try to click on a radio button (for example 'C'), angular tries to select the radio button which has a value equal to the value of the scope variable 'c_c_multiple'. As all of the radio buttons as that point do not have a specified value, a specific radio button cannot be targeted and selected.

If you initialise each of the four different scope variables that you are using for the four text areas to unique values, you will see that you are able to successfully select a radio button:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.radio = " ";
$scope.c_a_multiple = "a";
$scope.c_b_multiple = "b";
$scope.c_c_multiple = "c";
$scope.c_d_multiple = "d";
});
```

Please see this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K32eTZ7QsdKS6aAHuonX?p=preview), and the code below for a potential solution.

I have used ng-change to call a function in the controller whenever a radio button selection is changed or one of the input fields are updated. The function sets the value for $scope.radio, hence selecting the correct radio button, before then setting $scope.inputValue to the value of the chosen text area.

Main controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.updateInputValue = updateInputValue;

  function updateInputValue(radioButtonSelected){
    $scope.radio = radioButtonSelected;
     switch ($scope.radio) {
        case 'a':
            $scope.inputValue = $scope.c_a_multiple;
            break;
        case 'b':
            $scope.inputValue = $scope.c_b_multiple;
            break;
        case 'c':
            $scope.inputValue = $scope.c_c_multiple;
            break;
        case 'd':
            $scope.inputValue = $scope.c_d_multiple;
            break;
        default:
            $scope.inputValue = "";
            break;
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
{{inputValue}}

          <li><input type="radio" name="ChoiceGroup" ng-model="radio" value="a" ng-change="updateInputValue('a')">&nbsp;A</li>

          <li><textarea ng-model="c_a_multiple" ng-change="updateInputValue('a')" placeholder="type your choice A here"></textarea></li>

          <li><input type="radio" name="ChoiceGroup" ng-model="radio" value="b" ng-change="updateInputValue('b')">&nbsp;B</li>

          <li><textarea ng-model="c_b_multiple" ng-change="updateInputValue('b')" placeholder="type your choice B here"></textarea></li>

          <li><input type="radio" name="ChoiceGroup" ng-model="radio" value="c" ng-change="updateInputValue('c')">&nbsp;C</li>

          <li><textarea ng-model="c_c_multiple" ng-change="updateInputValue('c')" placeholder="type your choice C here"></textarea></li>

          <li><input type="radio" name="ChoiceGroup" ng-model="radio" value="d" ng-change="updateInputValue('d')">&nbsp;D</li>

          <li><textarea ng-model="c_d_multiple" ng-change="updateInputValue('d')" placeholder="type your choice D here"></textarea></li>
```